# Error await operator. Implementation correctly, but not work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, async-await

I tried create a file select and need list files. I am using await operator, but not work.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

    List<StorageFile> listOfFiles = new List<StorageFile>();
    await RetriveFilesInFolders(listOfFiles, folder);
    // as a result of above code I have a List of 5 files that are in Music Library

    List<IStorageItem> filesFolders = (await folder.GetItemsAsync()).ToList();
    List<StorageFile> items = (await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName)).ToList();

}

private async Task RetriveFilesInFolders(List<StorageFile> list, StorageFolder parent)
{
    foreach (var item in await parent.GetFilesAsync()) list.Add(item);
    foreach (var item in await parent.GetFoldersAsync()) await RetriveFilesInFolders(list, item);
}
```

and the Visual Studio show

> The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider
>   marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return
>   type to 'Task'

Comment: the error message is telling you what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `await` operator in your `OnNavigatedTo` method, which is not marked asynchronous by using the `async` modifier.
I'd say the message you got is pretty clear.